# Browser Stack Local not starting

Tags: browserstack

I am trying to test a web application running locally on localhost:3000 using BrowserStack to test different mobile resolutions. I've used this feature before with no issues but for some reason the "BrowserStackLocal" application is not running. I've tried running it from the dashboard and by using the shortcut on my desktop. Has anyone encountered this issue before? I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling BrowserStackLocal, selecting "run as administrator" and using different browsers (Chrome, Edge, Opera) but have not been able to get the local app to start. Using Task Manager I confirmed that BrowserStackLocal is not starting. I can access my web application in a browser (localhost:3000) just fine, but not through BrowserStack. Attached is a screenshot from BrowserStack dashboard. I have looked at the following documentation and followed the instructions but no luck. https://www.browserstack.com/docs/live/local-testing

Machine is running Windows 10

[image: BrowserStack Screenshot]

Comment: Did you fix it? I have the same problem

Comment: Same issue here. I also have a Windows machine, windows 11 pro.

Comment: I am still having the problem, but it's intermittent. I have no idea why sometimes it works and others it doesn't. I was able to use BrowserStack just fine last week, but today I'm having the same issue again.

Comment: Having the same problem, it stopped working out of nowhere and I can't get it to work again

Answer (score 0):

try `bs-local.com:3000` or `bs-local:3000`